# Rasp Pi3 VNC viewer only works if eth connected, either eth or wifi

Tags: wifi, vnc

TightVNC and VNC Viewer both work on either ethernet or wifi ip::port addresses if the e'net cable is plugged in. Neither work on wifi if the e'net cable is diconnected. The problem has been stated before, but so far, no answer.

I added the eth0 hotplug amd now Tightvnc gets a "target machine actively refused it" msg

Question: what do I do to get vnc to work when eth0 is unplugged ?

Comment: If you have asked the same question before repeating it won't get you any more answers. Your statement is untrue, both work perfectly well if correctly configured. I don't doubt you have a problem, but unless you provide more detail you won't get any help.

Comment: What detail should I include? The configs seem good to me, if a box with 2 pipes can suck and blow thru both pipes, but if I block 1 pipe, the other one stops too. I could not get the wifi to work at all using 46 google look-ups, until I found #47 which said to add addresses to the dhcpcd.conf file.

Comment: I did not repeat the question - I was told my 1st entry was not a question, so I edited it into a question.

Comment: Which of my statements is untrue?? I will try and correct it.

Comment: Additional detail: the wifi works without the ethernet cable connected - I can access the internet. But the vnc connectivity disappears.

Comment: To rule out the obvious have you checked the IP address assigned to the WiFi adapter of the Pi?  Are you sure you are using that address to connect when Ethernet not connected? What is the output of ifconfig both with and without Ethernet? Can you ping google from the Pi with Ethernet disconnected? Please add this info and answers to your question and not as commnets.

Comment: I read your description a few times and cannot tell if you run VNC server or VNC client on the affected Pi and where do you connect to/from.

Comment: All you have told us things look OK (to you). You haven't even said which OS. You have apparently modified files. List ALL you changed. If you type a command list EXACTLY what you enter and EXACTLY what the response is. Lastly check similar questions on this site (not Google).

Answer (score 0):

Summary (new Dec 5/16)

First, thanks all for your assistance. It is working.
I now have a laptop vncviewer accessing the Pi vncserver thru wifi with e'net disconnected.

I hope the following appears to you as an answer, and not a comment.
Although vnc works, Putty doesn't. The `auth.log` (accessed using vnc) shows the Putty pw accepted, but no response in the putty window on the pc. I can live with that.

The change I made which seems to have made it work is the inclusion of `eth0` lines in `dhcpcd.conf`.

Other details:
laptop: HP Pavilion Win10 running tvnviewer

Pi 3: ( 4 days old, 6 weeks in shipping)
os-release shows jessie 8

File: `/etc/network/interfaces`

```
source-directory /etc/network/interfaces.d
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback
allow-hotplug eth0
iface eth0 inet manual
allow-hotplug wlan0
iface wlan0 inet manual
    wpa-conf /etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant.conf
```

File: `/etc/dhcpcd.conf`

```
interface wlan0
static ip_address=192.168.2.50/22
static routers=192.168.2.1
static domain_name_servers=192.168.2.1
# following lines are the new ones
interface eth0
static ip_address=192.168.2.35/22
static routers=192.168.2.1
static domain_name_servers=192.168.2.1
```

Thanks again, folks, although would you agree the tone of most of the responses seems a tad combative? (that's a question!)
Also, a new user cannot complete the sign-up process using the Opera browser. This is being entered via Chrome.

Comment: Please accept your own answer with a click on the tick on its left side. Only this will finish the question and it will not pop up again year for year.